# Pod installation error: [!]Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named master

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cordova, github

I followed the steps on PhoneGap website and got stuck on the step using command "pod install" and got the error message as below:

MyMac:PhoneGapTest username$ **pod install**
Setting up CocoaPods master repo 
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.

Here is the information for my machine
1.  Mac OS 10.12 Sierra 
2.  Xcode 8.0 (8A218a) [Setting in “Xcode/Peference/Locations/Command Line Tools” is set to “Xcode 8.0 (8A218a)”, path is “/Application/Xcode.app”]

Please suggest on how to resolve this.  Thank you!

Comment: In terminal `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos` & reinstalling cocoapod worked in **summer 2018**

Comment: I actually added the repo manually by zipping from another Mac, you can also clone or download from the site https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

Answer (score 16):

If you recently installed the latest version of `XCode` in your mac, I would suggest to have a look at the `Preferences` once.

Go to **`XCode => Preferences => Locations`** and update the `Command Line Tools` like this:

[image]

Now try `pod update` and it will work like before.

Answer (score 14):

I had this issue on my mac as well.

Please go to this link: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293

I fixed this issue by doing the following:

- cd to `~/.cocoapods/repos`
- Run `git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master`

Tried update cocapods, re init pod and update repo, none of that works for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How much time did it take for you?

Comment: It takes a while, I remember it's over 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

@Mohshin Shah, thanks a lot.  You make my day!  I stucked with this for two weeks.  Your suggestion is the foundation to the workaround.  Below are what I've done.

----------------- first try: using buffer size as given -------------------
`My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ git config http.postBuffer 524288000

My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ pod install

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

[!] Unable to add a source with url https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git named master.

You can try adding it manually in ~/.cocoapods/repos or via pod repo add.`


-----------------  second try: double the buffer size -------------------------
`My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ git config http.postBuffer 1048576000

My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ pod install

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

[!] Unable to add a source with url https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git named master.

You can try adding it manually in ~/.cocoapods/repos or via pod repo add.`

-----------------  third try: the workaround, note: this might also work with the given buffer size --------------
`My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...

remote: Counting objects: 865802, done.

remote: Compressing objects: 100% (13060/13060), done.

remote: Total 865802 (delta 6507), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 851785

Receiving objects: 100% (865802/865802), 348.54 MiB | 948.00 KiB/s, done.

Resolving deltas: 100% (375143/375143), done.

Checking connectivity... done.

Checking out files: 100% (114193/114193), done.`

-----------------  checking the result -------------------------
`My-Mac:PhoneGapTest username$ ls

    PhoneGapTest        PhoneGapTestTests   Podfile         Pods

    PhoneGapTest.xcodeproj  PhoneGapTestUITests     master`

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed by running:

1)$ rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
2)$ mkdir -p ~/.cocoapods/repos
3)$ cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
4)$ git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Answer (score 0):

This might be because 2 factor Authentication.You might have enabled the 2 Factor Authentication so your password is not the Github password now it is the password which is result of 2 factor authentication. 
You can get your password by

opening Cmd+Space ->>Search for Keychain Access ->> Open KeyChain access ->> Click on search ->> search your username of Github ->> click on the Result of search ->> Click on show Password ->> Copy the password 
and paste it on terminal when it asks for password